# Allow entering/copying-pasting only numbers into wpf PasswordBox like TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

You are allowing to enter only numbers into TextBox thanks to following code.

Following code is okey.

```
Private Sub Textbox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles Textbox1.TextChanged
    Dim myRegex As New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[^\d]")
    Textbox1.Text = myRegex.Replace(Textbox1.Text, "")
End Sub
```

I need same action for PasswordBox.

Following code gives this error: https://prnt.sc/ljk9ty

```
Private Sub PasswordBox1_PasswordChanged(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles PasswordBox1.PasswordChanged
    Dim myRegex As New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[^\d]")
    PasswordBox1.Password = myRegex.Replace(PasswordBox1.Password, "")
End Sub
```

So, the code above is need to be repaired.

Comment: Calculate the result into a temp variable and only assign to the password box if the value is different

Comment: Use data binding with commands...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could register PreviewTextInput event and validate the input of user. If the input is not a number, you could set the value of e.Handled as true to ignore this input.

```
private void PasswordBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("[0-9]+");
    if (!regex.IsMatch(e.Text))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I got your requirement clear now, this is how you can handle the input both cases

```
    private void PasswordBox1_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex myRegex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"[^\d]");
        if (myRegex.IsMatch(PasswordBox1.Password))
            PasswordBox1.Password = myRegex.Replace(PasswordBox1.Password, "");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. How about if user copy text and paste it to PasswordBox?

Comment: see my updates above how to disable the paste command on passwordbox

Comment: User should copy and paste numbers but not text. This is what I want.

Comment: See my updates above for the fix to handle both cases.